# Button Is Disabled but Still Listens to Press Event

Tags: sapui5

I have a submit button in a `<VBox>`. On press of it, I have an order creation process. If I click multiple times on the button, multiple orders are created. Is there a way I can disable it after the first click?

I have written the following code in my controller, but it seems to be still hearing to the press action:

```js
onSubmit: function(oEvent) { 
  this.getView().byId("save").setVisible(false);  
  //......
},
```

But this does not disable completely. Though in console, when I check using `getEnabled()`, it is set to `false`. How to stop the button from listening to press event when disabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can suggest the following solutions:

1. Right after the button got clicked - set its "*enabled*" property to "*false*" **via property binding against JSON model**. Once the *async* action got executed (i.e. *success/fail* callbacks) - release the button state by setting "*enabled*" to "*true*"
2. Right after the button got clicked - set its "*busy*" property to "*true*" (do not forget to set the "*busyIndicatorDelay*" to 0. The releasing concept is the same as for point 1.

In my opinion, these approaches are more UI5 specific. Personally I would choose the option 2, as it shows the state of processing something in a more prominent way to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think the problem is that setVisible is not the same as enables/disabled. 
Maybe you could try to change

```
setVisible(false);
```

to

```
setAttribute("disabled", true);
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Happy I could help. If it worked please accept the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Hope the bellow code will work fine. Making `SetVisible(false)` you just hide the button.

```
Controller: onSubmit: function(oEvent) { this.getView().byId("save").setAttribute("disabled", true);
```

check this: https://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/d/147187-how-to-disable-enable-submit-button-using-javascript
for detail understanding